# Python: standard deviation of gaussian weighted pixel region

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to calculate a Gaussian weighted standard deviation of a 2D array with Python, does anyone know how to do this? So basically apply a 2D Gaussian filter but instead of returning the convolution of each array element with the filter, I would like it to return the standard deviation of the Gaussian weighted values around some array element.

cheers,
Tomas

Answer (score 1):

There is a numpy function called std. Example

```
    x = np.random.uniform(0,5,(20,20))
    np.std(x)
```

And this will return the standard deviation of the 20x20 array. If you want a specific portion of the image you can use array splicing to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

For a non weighted filter that returns the local standard deviation for 2D arrays, you could use,

```
scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(image, function=np.std, size=(10, 10))
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a function to do what you want in standard scientific python modules. You would probably have to write your own implementation (see the general approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024192/1791279) ).

Comment: Thanks @rth, indeed a filter like that is what I am looking for, but then with a Gaussian weight.